# html2canvas send back to server react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, html2canvas

It is going to be a long post, I appreciate your patience.

I'm trying to take a screenshot of `<FormList />` component in the `<TemplateRealEstate />` using `html2canvas` library and send to backend to server.

`<FormList />` components return `<ul> <FormItem /> </ul>`. So basically, display some house informations.

I got so confused how to send back to server. I tested and it can display in the same page, but I need to display in another component that is nor child neither parent component. I tried with Context and didn't result. So I'm trying to send back to server to display.

`<TemplateRealEstate />` rendering under `http://localhost:3000/pages/:pageId`. You need to create a page first to create templates. So page controllers normally takes

```
const createdPage = new Page({
    name,
    area,
    tema,
    type,
    creator,
    screenshot
  });
```

and when I create page I got these field values;

```
area: "Real Estate"
creator: "63a6612aaa0e288b21afe2d2"
name: "LABA"
screenshot: undefined
tema: "Boho"
type: "Basic"
```

After created page, and created template as well, I have a button to take a screenshot of a div in `<TemplateRealEstate />`

When I trigger button to set screenshot I got `Successfully sent screenshot to server: {data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: 'Created', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}` but does not add field as **screenshot** neither updates the value. It returns like this;

```
page: 
area:"Real Estate"
creator:"63a6612aaa0e288b21afe2d2"
id:"63a6f6ed7e0d858bc283a79c"
name:"LABA"
tema:"Boho"
type:"Basic"
__v:0
_id:"63a6f6ed7e0d858bc283a79c"
```

I've tried with all of **Content-Type**s.

**TemplateRealEstate.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import domtoimage from "dom-to-image";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";

import FormList from "../components/FormList";

import "./TemplateRealEstate.css";

const TemplateRealEstate = () => {
  const [loadedTemplates, setLoadedTemplates] = useState([]);
  const [screenshot, setScreenshot] = useState(null);
  const [screenshotFile, setScreenshotFile] = useState(null);
  const [screenshotUrl, setScreenshotUrl] = useState(null);

  const pageId = useParams().pageId;

  // Define a helper function to convert a data URI to a Blob object
  const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
    // Convert the data URI to a binary string
    const binaryString = window.atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);

    // Get the MIME type from the data URI
    const mimeType = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

    // Create an ArrayBuffer from the binary string
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryString.length);
    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
      uint8Array[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // Return the Blob object
    return new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: mimeType });
  };

  const handleScreenshot = () => {
    // Select the element you want to take a screenshot of
    const element = document.getElementById("my-element");

    // Use the html2canvas function to render the element as a canvas element
    html2canvas(element)
      .then((canvas) => {
        const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();

        // Convert the data URI to a Blob object
        const blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURI);

        // Set the screenshot file
        setScreenshotFile(blob);

        // Create a new FormData object
        const formData = new FormData();

        // Add the screenshot as a file field to the form
        formData.append("screenshot", blob, "screenshot.png");

        // Set the screenshot as a prop or state variable in the NewPage component

        // Send the screenshot to the backend
        axios
          .patch(`http://localhost:8080/api/pages/${pageId}`, formData, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("Successfully sent screenshot to server:", res);
            setScreenshot(formData);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Failed to send screenshot to server:", err);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed to take screenshot:", error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (screenshotFile) {
      // Create a new FileReader object
      const reader = new FileReader();

      // Set the onload event handler
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        // Set the screenshot data URL
        setScreenshotUrl(event.target.result);
      };

      // Read the image file
      reader.readAsDataURL(screenshotFile);
    }
  }, [screenshotFile]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="my-element">
        <FormList items={loadedTemplates} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={redirectToForm}>Add house</button>

      <button type="button" onClick={handleScreenshot}>
        Set screenshot
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Page</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TemplateRealEstate;
```

**Page controller in server**

```
// PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/pages/:pid
const updatePageById = async (req, res, next) => {
  //const stores the address of the object and not the object it self
  const pageId = req.params.pid;
  const screenshot = req.file;

  try {
    page = await Page.findById(pageId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      // this error will display if our get request generally has some kind of a problem
      "Something went wrong, could not update a page with that ID.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  // applying if statement, won't lose the data if the user only wants to update one field instead of given all req.body
  if (screenshot) page.screenshot = screenshot;

  try {
    await page.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not update page",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.status(201).json({ page: page.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `multipart/form-data`? Also, you can just use [`canvas.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob).

Comment: I've literally tried every content-type...

Comment: What I wanted to do is, display the website preview like in CodeSandBox. Before clicking it, it displays what already contains inside of it. Are there anyway I can achieve that?

Comment: I've used iframe instead of screenshot libraries! And it solved my problem